# Windows Phone sign in user on phone and service

Tags: authentication, service, windows-phone-8, single-sign-on

I would like to implement the following scenario:
There is a WP8 app in which the user uses his Live Id account to sign in. Once the user is signed in he can use the services (hosted on Azure) through the application.

I want to provide a single sign on experience, meaning that I want the user to sign in on the phone and automatically be authorized also on the server.

I know how to sign in a user on the phone and I know how to sign in a user on the web (interactive) but I do not know how can I connect the two. What is the best way to authenticate the user in both places?

I need a way to validate that whoever sends data through the service is indeed the user who logged in on the phone. Basically I need something like Azure Mobile Services, where the data base calls from the client are authenticated, but for my own REST service.

My guess is that I need some sort of shared validation service that can check if a user is logged in but I am not sure what's the right approach to implement this.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826544.aspx